# Visual Studio Decompiled Source Definitions from Object Browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, decompiling, ilspy

In Visual Studio 2019, there is a new feature powered by ILSpy to view decompiled source definitions(C#). It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2019#view-decompiled-source-definitions-instead-of-metadata-c).

This is a great feature and when I have a snippet of code like,

```
SomeExternalClass.MemberFunction()
```

I can click right click and goto definition and it will take me to the decompiled source definition.

My question is how do I get that to work from the object browser. While browsing objects if I right click and Browse Definition it doesn't take me to the decompiled source definition.

Currently I have to manually call that class/function somewhere in my code just to use the goto definition feature.

Is there a way to do this, that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I can access this in the Object Browser by right-clicking the item, and selecting "Navigate > Decompiled Sources"
NB This is VS2022